# UFT - JavaTable unable to get text

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

I have this code for HP UFT v12.54

```
For itC = 0 To rwTbl - 1 Step 1
For itcC = 0 To clTbl - 1 Step 1
    worksheet1.Cells(itC+1,itcC+1).value = objNPC_tp.GetCellData(itC, itcC)
Next
Next
```

The javatable has 5 columns, the output in my excel file is incomplete.

3 columns have the expected value that I want but the two other columns are empty.

It seems GetCellData is only able to get the text for cells with JavaEdit and JavaStaticText class. The other 2 column that have multiple  class within a cell such as Links, Dropdowns, etc. GetCellData is unable to get the text value.

I also tried using childObjects without success.

Is there any other method I could try to get the text value from a cell inside a javatable?

Comment: Is anything selected in the dropdown? Are the links set in cell?

Comment: Hi yes some rows have selected dropdown values. The links are set inside the cell.